# Chart.js- Dates not displaying correctly on chart and axis labels not showing

Tags: javascript, django, chart.js

I'm trying to label my axes on my chart. I'm using chart.js v3.9.1 and I believe I've followed the documentation, however the labels aren't showing up (see below):[image]

health_hub_tracker.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Weight Tracker</h1>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [{%for stat in date%}{{stat}},{%endfor%}],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Weight (lbs)',
            data: [{%for stat in weight%}{{stat}},{%endfor%}],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    Text: 'Date'
                }
            },
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    Text: 'Weight (lbs)'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py:

```
def health_hub_tracker(request):
    serialized_weight = []
    serialized_date = []
    for stats in HealthStats.objects.filter(user=request.user):
        serialized_weight.append(int(
            stats.weight,
        ))
        date_only = stats.date.date()
        serialized_date.append(str(
            date_only
        ))
    print(serialized_weight)
    print(serialized_date)
    context = {
        "weight": serialized_weight,
        "date": serialized_date
        }
    return render(request, "health_hub_tracker.html", context)
```

You will also see that on my x axis- the dates are coming through as a sum.

The data I have are:
['2022-10-09', '2022-10-09', '2022-10-05', '2022-10-05', '2022-10-05']

so it is literally calculating 2022-10-09 to give 2003 and so on. What am I missing here? I would like to display the date as a string, as per the list of data I'm getting in my view.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here seems to be the lack of string delimiters around your dates.

The labels property without the delimiters ends up being something like this in your generated HTML.

```
labels: [2022-10-09, 2022-10-09, 2022-10-05, 2022-10-05, 2022-10-05],
```

JS processor, upon seeing `2022-10-09` assumes you want to calculate the result of subtracting 10 and 9 from 2022.

What you want to end up with is

```
labels: ['2022-10-09', '2022-10-09', '2022-10-05', '2022-10-05', '2022-10-05'],
```

and for that you have to change your labels iteration code to something like this (I'm not really familiar with Python or Django, but you get the idea ;) )

```
labels: [{%for stat in date%}'{{stat}}',{%endfor%}],
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your X axis contains dates, you should specify it in your options :

```
options: {
    scales: {
        x: {
            type : 'time', ...
        }
    }
}
```

Because X axis type is by default `category`, and for this to work, you should also include a time adapter like [date-fns](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns) (more info [here](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#adapters)), and according to the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters) :

> The time scale requires both a ***date library*** and a corresponding ***adapter*** to be present.

That's why I personally use `date-fns` because it's all bundled in one file, and if you need date formatting (for labels and tooltips for example), here is the [format page](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format).